# Add Image To The TinyMCE Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using `TinyMCE` editor to insert formatted text and one of my requirement is to insert images with contents like wrapping text over the image. So I've planned to make it work in another way. What I am doing now, uploading the image with `HTML` file upload and then inserting demo contents into the editor. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#sample img').click(function () {
       tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Hello World!');
   });
});
```

So with the above code, I upload the image first, then making the image clickable and finally inserting some default texts into the editor. Sample image:

[image: Sample Image]
Now I want to insert the image to the editor, so I was trying to retrieve the image source something like the below but unable to do so:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<img src='' />');
```

I am not sure but seems like I am missing something here. Would really appreciate if someone makes me understand on this - Thanks. The full code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#sample img').click(function () {
             tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('Hello World!');
       });
  });  

 tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea></textarea>

  <span id="sample">
     <img id="blah" alt="Upload Image Here" width="100" height="100" />
  </span>

  <input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify onchange event some thing like this:

```
<input type="file" onchange="document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); 
     tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() + '<img src=\"'+document.getElementById('blah').src + '\"/>')"/>
```

This should work.

Or another option is to create a function which performs this operation:

```
function onChangeEvent()
{
   document.getElementById('blah').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
   tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() + 
   '<img src="'+document.getElementById('blah').src + '"/>')/>
}
```

And then input looks like:

```
<input type="file" onchange="onChangeEvent()">
```

Comment: OK - Thanks for the answer @SouXin. I'll be trying it and notify you.